# iOS BLE and ESP32 BLE communication is not working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

The connection is setup and the app connects to ESP32 but I am not able to send or receive data. I want to send data as I have written in the code but when I check the serial monitor after the conversion from string to char, it is not accurate as how I want. It will be of great help if someone could help me out with it. I am posting the code. Please help

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  LaytonBat
//
//  Created by Rohan Dengle on 1/27/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  // App Variables
  @State private var angle0 = false
  @State private var angle15 = false
  @State private var angle45 = false
  @State private var vibration = false
  @State private var vibrationText = "OFF"
  @State private var sound = false
  @State private var soundText = "OFF"
  @State private var light = false
  @State private var lightText = "OFF"
  @State private var negativeFeedback = false
  @State private var negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
  @State private var blastMode = false
  @State private var setAngle = -10
  @State private var batAngle = 0
  @State private var vibration1 = false
  @State private var vibrationText1 = "OFF"
  @State private var sound1 = false
  @State private var soundText1 = "OFF"
  @State private var light1 = false
  @State private var lightText1 = "OFF"
  @State private var negativeFeedback1 = false
  @State private var negativeFeedbackText1 = "OFF"
  @State private var blastMode1 = false
  @State private var batSpeed = 0
  @State private var currentView: Int = 0
  @State var Bunt = true
  @State private var showingPopover = false
  @State private var showingPopover1 = false
  @State private var showingPopover2 = false
    
  // Bluetooth Variables
  var bluetooth = Bluetooth.shared
  @State var presented: Bool = false
  @State var list = [Bluetooth.Device]()
  @State var isConnected: Bool = Bluetooth.shared.current != nil { didSet {
    if isConnected {
      presented.toggle()
    }
    else{
      angle45 = false
      angle0 = false
      angle15 = false
      light = false
      sound = false
      vibration = false
      blastMode = false
      negativeFeedback = false
      setAngle = -10
      vibrationText = "OFF"
      soundText = "OFF"
      lightText = "OFF"
      negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
    }
  } }
  
  @State var response = Data() { didSet {
    if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "49"){
      angle0 = true
      angle15 = false
      angle45 = false
      blastMode = false
      setAngle = 0
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "50"){
      angle15 = true
      angle0 = false
      angle45 = false
      blastMode = false
      setAngle = 15
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "51"){
      angle45 = true
      angle0 = false
      angle15 = false
      blastMode = false
      setAngle = 45
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "54"){
      light = true
      lightText = "ON"
      light1 = true
      lightText1 = "ON"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "55"){
      light = false
      lightText = "OFF"
      light1 = false
      lightText1 = "OFF"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "56"){
      negativeFeedback = true
      negativeFeedbackText = "ON"
      negativeFeedback1 = true
      negativeFeedbackText = "ON"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "57"){
      negativeFeedback = false
      negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
      negativeFeedback1 = false
      negativeFeedbackText1 = "OFF"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "97"){
      vibration = true
      vibrationText = "ON"
      vibration1 = true
      vibrationText1 = "ON"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "98"){
      vibration = false
      vibrationText = "OFF"
      vibration1 = false
      vibrationText1 = "OFF"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "52"){
      sound = true
      soundText = "ON"
      sound1 = true
      soundText1 = "ON"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "53"){
      sound = false
      soundText = "OFF"
      sound1 = true
      soundText1 = "OFF"
    }
    else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "l"){
      blastMode = true
      setAngle = -10
      angle45 = false
      angle0 = false
      angle15 = false
      light = false
      sound = false
      vibration = false
      negativeFeedback = false
      vibrationText = "OFF"
      soundText = "OFF"
      lightText = "OFF"
      negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
      light1 = false
      sound1 = false
      vibration1 = false
      negativeFeedback1 = false
      vibrationText1 = "OFF"
      soundText1 = "OFF"
      lightText1 = "OFF"
      negativeFeedbackText1 = "OFF"
    }
    else{
      batAngle = Int(String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) ?? "0") ?? 0
    }
  } }
  @State var string: String = ""
  @State var value: Float = 0
  @State var state: Bool = false { didSet { bluetooth.send([UInt8(state.int)]) } }
  
  @State var editing = false
  
    var body: some View {
//      let degreeOfFreedom = 5
      //let batAngle = Int(String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) ?? "0") ?? 0
      
      ZStack{
          
              VStack{
                  
                  Button {
                      presented.toggle()
                  } label: {
                      HStack {
                          Text("Connect to Bat")
                              .bold()
                          ZStack {
                              Image("bluetooth")
                                  .resizable()
                                  .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                  .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: 35)
                  .background(Color.green)
                  
                  Group{
                  Image("logo")
                      .resizable()
                      .scaledToFill()
                      .frame(width: 200, height: 80)
                      HStack (spacing:20){
                      Spacer()
                      Image("Bunt")
                          .resizable()
                          .scaledToFill()
                          .frame(width: 60, height: 85)
                      Spacer()
                      Image("Swing")
                          .resizable()
                          .scaledToFill()
                          .frame(width: 95, height: 60)
                      Spacer()
                      Image("Blast")
                          .resizable()
                          .scaledToFill()
                          .frame(width: 90, height: 80)
                      Spacer()
                  }
              }
              VStack{
                  HStack (spacing : 10){
                      
                          Button("Bunt Mode"){
                              showingPopover = true
                              }
                              .padding(13.0)
                              .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                              .foregroundColor(.white)
                              .font(.headline)
                              .clipShape(Capsule())
                          
                      .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover){
                          BuntView()
                      }
                      
                              Button("Swing Mode"){
                                  showingPopover1 = true
                              }
                              .padding(13.0)
                              .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                              .foregroundColor(.white)
                              .font(.headline)
                              .clipShape(Capsule())
                      
                      .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover1){
                          SwingView()
                      }
                      
                      Button("Blast Mode"){
                          showingPopover2 = true
                      }
                              .padding(13.0)
                              .background(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
                              .foregroundColor(.white)
                              .font(.headline)
                              .clipShape(Capsule())
                      
                      .popover(isPresented: $showingPopover2){
                          FunView()
                      }
                      
                  }
                  Spacer()
                 
              }
              
              .navigationTitle("Content View")
          
          
        }
          Spacer()
          Spacer()
        
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $presented){ ScanView(bluetooth: bluetooth, presented: $presented, list: $list, isConnected: $isConnected) }
      .onAppear{ bluetooth.delegate = self }
    }
    
    
  
  func sendValue(_ value: Float) {
      if Int(value) != Int(self.value) {
          guard let sendValue = map(Int(value), of: 0...100, to: 0...255) else { return }
          bluetooth.send([UInt8(state.int), UInt8(sendValue)])
      }
      self.value = value
  }

  func map(_ value: Int, of: ClosedRange<Int>, to: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int? {
      guard let ofmin = of.min(), let ofmax = of.max(), let tomin = to.min(), let tomax = to.max() else { return nil }
      return Int(tomin + (tomax - tomin) * (value - ofmin) / (ofmax - ofmin))
  }

}


struct BuntView: View{
    // App Variables
    @State private var angle0 = false
    @State private var angle15 = false
    @State private var angle45 = false
    @State private var vibration = false
    @State private var vibrationText = "OFF"
    @State private var sound = false
    @State private var soundText = "OFF"
    @State private var light = false
    @State private var lightText = "OFF"
    @State private var negativeFeedback = false
    @State private var negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
    @State private var blastMode = false
    @State private var setAngle = -10
    @State private var batAngle = 0
    @State private var currentView: Int = 0
    @State private var Bunt: Bool = true
    @State private var vibration1 = false
    @State private var vibrationText1 = "OFF"
    @State private var sound1 = false
    @State private var soundText1 = "OFF"
    @State private var light1 = false
    @State private var lightText1 = "OFF"
    @State private var negativeFeedback1 = false
    @State private var negativeFeedbackText1 = "OFF"
    @State private var blastMode1 = false
    
    @State var response = Data() { didSet {
        if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "49"){
        angle0 = true
        angle15 = false
        angle45 = false
        blastMode = false
        setAngle = 0
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "50"){
        angle15 = true
        angle0 = false
        angle45 = false
        blastMode = false
        setAngle = 15
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "51"){
        angle45 = true
        angle0 = false
        angle15 = false
        blastMode = false
        setAngle = 45
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "54"){
        light = true
        lightText = "ON"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "55"){
        light = false
        lightText = "OFF"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "56"){
        negativeFeedback = true
        negativeFeedbackText = "ON"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "57"){
        negativeFeedback = false
        negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "97"){
        vibration = true
        vibrationText = "ON"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "98"){
        vibration = false
        vibrationText = "OFF"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "52"){
        sound = true
        soundText = "ON"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "53"){
        sound = false
        soundText = "OFF"
      }
      else if (String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) == "l"){
        blastMode = true
        setAngle = -10
        angle45 = false
        angle0 = false
        angle15 = false
        light = false
        sound = false
        vibration = false
        negativeFeedback = false
        vibrationText = "OFF"
        soundText = "OFF"
        lightText = "OFF"
        negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
      }
      else{
        batAngle = Int(String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) ?? "0") ?? 0
      }
    } }
    @State var string: String = ""
    @State var value: Float = 0
    @State var state: Bool = false { didSet { bluetooth.send([UInt8(state.int)]) } }
    
    // Bluetooth Variables
    var bluetooth = Bluetooth.shared
    @State var presented: Bool = false
    @State var list = [Bluetooth.Device]()
    @State var isConnected: Bool = Bluetooth.shared.current != nil { didSet {
      if isConnected {
        presented.toggle()
      }
      else{
        angle45 = false
        angle0 = false
        angle15 = false
        light = false
        sound = false
        vibration = false
        blastMode = false
        negativeFeedback = false
        setAngle = -10
        vibrationText = "OFF"
        soundText = "OFF"
        lightText = "OFF"
        negativeFeedbackText = "OFF"
      }
    } }
var body: some View {
    if Bunt{
        let degreeOfFreedom = 5
        VStack{
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 70)
            Image("Bunt")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 80)
            
            Text("Set Angle")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                .italic()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    bluetooth.send(Array("1".utf8))
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                            .foregroundColor(angle0 ? .green : .gray)
                        Text("0°")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    bluetooth.send(Array("2".utf8))
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                            .foregroundColor(angle15 ? .green : .gray)
                        Text("15°")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    bluetooth.send(Array("3".utf8))
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                            .foregroundColor(angle45 ? .green : .gray)
                        Text("45°")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
            Text("Current Angle")
                .font(.title2)
                .bold()
                .italic()
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            Text(isConnected ? "\(batAngle)°" : "Not Connected")
                .bold()
                .font(.system(size: 42))
                .foregroundColor(isConnected ? (((batAngle < setAngle+degreeOfFreedom)&&(batAngle > setAngle-degreeOfFreedom)) ? .green : .black) : .red)
                .scaleEffect(isConnected ? 1.5 : 0.8)
                .offset(x: isConnected ? 10 : 0)
            VStack{
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: 350, height: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Text("Feedback")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .italic()
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Sound")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .italic()
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        if sound == true{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("b".utf8))
                        }
                        else{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("a".utf8))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(sound ? .green : .gray)
                                .animation(.linear)
                            Text("\(soundText)")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Light")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .italic()
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        //light.toggle()
                        if light == true{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("5".utf8))
                        }
                        else{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("4".utf8))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(light ? .green : .gray)
                                .animation(.linear)
                            Text("\(lightText)")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Vibration")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .italic()
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        if vibration == true{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("9".utf8))
                        }
                        else{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("8".utf8))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(vibration ? .green : .gray)
                                .animation(.linear)
                            
                            Text("\(vibrationText)")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                VStack{
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .opacity(0.50)
                        
                        Text("Negative Feedback")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .bold()
                            .italic()
                    }
                    Button {
                        if negativeFeedback == true{
                            if negativeFeedback == true{
                                bluetooth.send(Array("7".utf8))
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            bluetooth.send(Array("6".utf8))
                        }
                    } label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Capsule()
                                .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(negativeFeedback ? .green : .gray)
                                .animation(.linear)
                            Text("\(negativeFeedbackText)")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 350, height: 90)
                
                
            }
        }
    }
}
 
}

 
    }




struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct BuntView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BuntView()
    }
}

struct SwingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwingView()
    }
}

struct FunView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FunView()
    }
}

extension ContentView: BluetoothProtocol {
func state(state: Bluetooth.State) {
    switch state {
    case .unknown: print("◦ .unknown")
    case .resetting: print("◦ .resetting")
    case .unsupported: print("◦ .unsupported")
    case .unauthorized: print("◦ bluetooth disabled, enable it in settings")
    case .poweredOff: print("◦ turn on bluetooth")
    case .poweredOn: print("◦ everything is ok")
    case .error: print("• error")
    case .connected:
        print("◦ connected to \(bluetooth.current?.name ?? "")")
        isConnected = true
    case .disconnected:
        print("◦ disconnected")
        isConnected = false
    }
}

func list(list: [Bluetooth.Device]) { self.list = list }

func value(data: Data) { response = data }
}
```

I have tried converting from string to char but there is no transmission or reception of data

Comment: It is easier for people to help you if you can provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you been able to test the ESP32 end of the Bluetooth link with a generic BLE scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile). What is the details of the BLE GATT service you are connecting to?

Comment: I am connecting to SERVICE_UUID "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" 
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_RX "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_TX "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

Comment: Those UUID's are normally used for the Nordic UART profile and they have an example app at: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Toolbox

Comment: I did check it and tried to implement it but there is no transmission or reception of data.

Comment: It is a complex example I'll grant you but isn't this sending data? https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-nRF-Toolbox/blob/253c56afdcf82fa6a007caa1a402007119004144/nRF%20Toolbox/BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.swift#L171-L246

Comment: I wasn't able to. Tbh, I am completely new to this and this is my first ever hands-on experience on swift. So, I need a bit of an elaborated explanation on how to go about it.